# AngularJS - $http not use JSONP

Tags: ajax, json, rest, angularjs, jsonp

I have defined a $http.get method, and the problem is that if I do not provide it with a JSONP response, it cannot parse the result, anyone know a way to use JSON REST service? I don't want to burden the server with JSONP transformation of results.

Thanks!

[MY SERVICE CLASS]

```
class PostService
  constructor: ($log, $http) ->
    urlBase = 'api/posts'

    PostService::get = ($log)->
      $http.get(urlBase).then((result) ->
        result.data
      )

angular.module('app').service 'postService', ['$log', '$http', PostService]
```

[MY CONTROLLER CLASS]

```
    class PostController
      constructor:($log, $location, $scope,postService) ->

        setPosts = =>
          postService.get($log).then (result) =>
            $scope.posts = result

        setPosts()

    angular.module('app').controller 'postController', ['$log', '$location', '$scope','postService',  PostController]
```

Comment: Can you please paste a sample code here? Because normally AngularJS's $http.get works fine with a plain vanilla JSON REST API. It should not be expecting JSONP packaging. So it has to be some other issue.

Comment: alright i'll add code to the main question. (wrote in coffee script)

Comment: Can you trying using the HttpPromises's .success callback instead of the .then base callback? Also have you verified that your JSON is valid? Because based on your code it should work fine without any issues. Is the error getting thrown inside Angular's HTTP code or after it reaches your callback? Also do see if something like this works:

$http.get("api/posts").success (data, status) ->
  console.log data

Comment: Thank you Dennis, after displaying the Json response, I found out that the problem was related to the fact that I exported the mongo OID , which could not be interpreted by JSON.